# Trying to make an android app in which the phone acting as a Server

Tags: android

Trying to figure a way in which the phone app acting as a broadcaster over UDP protocol stop listening as soon as it encounters a datagaram packet as reply.
Can't use google cloud need the app to be lightweight

Answer (score 0):

You you want that your android phone act as server. then you can  that using this https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd